# Неправильно считается среднее арифметическое

Tags: java

Дана последовательность чисел. Определить,есть ли среди них числа, равные среднему арифметическому всех членов последовательности.

```
package com.company;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.Random;

public class masss
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int s = 0;
        int sr = 0;
        String c = "null";

        System.out.println("Введите количество элементов: ");
        int[] a = new int[new Scanner(System.in).nextInt()];


        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            a[i] = (int) (Math.random() * 10 + 1);
            s += a[i];
        }
        sr /= a.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(a[i] + " ");

        }
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        {
            if (a[i] == sr)
                c = "Да";
            else c = "нет";
        }
        System.out.println(c + "  ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Неправильно это как и на каких данных?

Comment: Введите количество элементов: 
3    
8 6 4 нет

Comment: 3 это количество элементов

Comment: В вопрос эту информацию добавьте...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто избавьтесь от переменной `sr`, и в местах обращения к ней замените на `s`.

Все дело в том, что вы сумму чисел храните в переменной `s`, но при этом для получения среднего арифметического делите переменную `sr`, которая как была 0, так и осталась 0 (т.к. вы сумму клали не в неё, а в `s`), на длину массива входных данных: `sr /= a.length;`. В итоге, вы всегда получали 0 в качестве стреднего арифметического. Таким образом `sr` здесь вообще избыточная переменная, которая ни к месту.

---

Так как у вас же берется целая часть от деления на размер массива входных данных (`sr /= a.length;` так как `sr` является переменной целого типа, то дробная часть результата деления откидывается), а вам требуется, чтобы среднее арифметического точно совпадало с одним из элементов массива, то можно добавить следующую проверку в конец программы на место вашего `for`, который выдает "Да"/"Нет".

Таким образом, примерный вариант подходящей вам реализации с минимальными правками:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Введите количество элементов: ");
    int[] a = new int[new Scanner(System.in).nextInt()];

    int s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; ++i)
    {
        a[i] = (int)(Math.random()*10 + 1);
        s += a[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        System.out.print(a[i] + " ");

    int rest = s % a.length; // получаем остаток от деления
    // если остаток от деления != 0, то значит среднее арифметическое не является целым числом,
    // а следовательно, заведомо ни одна из наших чисел не равно ему (даже проверять не надо), т.к. вы числа генерируете как случайные целые
    if (0 == rest)
    {
        s /= a.length;

        // идем по всем элементам массива пока он не закончится, т.е. условаие (i < a.length)
        // либо пока не найдем число == среднемму арифметическому, т.е. условие (s != a[i])
        int i = 0;
        for (; i < a.length && s != a[i]; ++i){}

        // если номер индекс элемента массива i, на котором мы вышли из предыдущего for != размерам массива,
        // значит в массиве имеется число == среднему арифметическому
        // если что, то "? :" - это "тернарный оператор" - загуглите
        System.out.println((i != a.length) ? "Да" : "Нет");
    }
    else
        System.out.println("Нет");
}
```

Comment: @Liona Добавил в конец ответа пример того, как можно этого избежать.

Comment: А зачем в конец вы добавили    else
    System.out.println("Нет");

Comment: @Liona потому, что если имеется остаток от деления (!= 0), то ни одно из ваших чисел заведомо не равно среднему арифметическому, т.к. все ваши числа целые, результат среднего арифметического не является целым числом.

Comment: Введите количество элементов: 
3
элементы:
4
5
3
Нет

Comment: @Liona Просто я даже не стал вникать в алгоритм проверки в этом `for` (решил оставить так, как было, но раз возникли сложности, то расписал), сейчас в конце ответа я поправил его.

Comment: @Liona Проблема решилась?

Comment: @Liona Окей, я всю переписанную функцию `main` в конец ответа добавил с комментариями.

Comment: Вы гений)Всё получилось